# Як вимовляється "США" (Сполучені Штати Америки)?

Tags: фонетика, скорочення

Варіянтів може бути декілька:

1. сешеа́
2. сша
3. шша
4. есшаа́

Перший варіянт найбільш логічний, бо НБУ = "енбеу́", ЦРУ = "цереу́", ТРК = "теерка́" (хоча ЗІП = "зіп"), але я не чув, щоби так казали (вочевидь, є неправильним).

Пам'ятаю, в школі мені казали, що правильний саме третій варіянт.

Дикторка ТСН [вимовляє](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36yIbtxIduo&feature=youtu.be&t=8s) щось середнє між другим і третім.

То як же правильно? Чи існує правило, яке це регулює?

Comment: Перший варіант насправді нелогічний, бо в українській мові немає літери «се» — лише «ес». (Хоча, можливо, є правило, що предписує його вимовляти саме так на початку абревіатури — а, можливо, воно є в російській мові.) Також, до речі, «ша», а не «ше» — тоді вже «ес-ша-а».

Comment: @Sasha  слушне зауваження. Навіть не задумувався над цим. Здається,  я не один такий. [Алла Мазур говорить](https://youtu.be/ZMdY6vjjznY?t=16s)

Comment: Ну, «се-ше-а» точно говорите не один Ви. [В росіян це взагалі майже норма](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/60-rubric-91).

Comment: «Есшаá» ніяк неможливо людей змусити говорити, так само, як і «еферéн», я пробував.

Answer (score 12):

Олександр Авраменко, доцент Київського університету імені Бориса Грінченка, завідувач кафедри гуманітарних дисциплін Технічного ліцею НТУУ "КПІ", у своєму [експрес-уроці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS0jzfuSn8M) в програмі "Сніданок з 1+1" стверджує, що абревіатура **`США`** читається **`сша`** як виняток, як і **`ЗМІ`** **`змі`**.

Загальне правило ж таке:

- Якщо у складі абревіатури є голосні літери, то вона читається як звичайне слово: `ЦУМ`, `ВАТ`, `ЧАЕС`.
- Якщо ж голосного в середині абревіатури немає, то її вимовляють, називаючи кожну букву як в алфавіті:  **`МЗС`** [ем-зе-ес], **`СБУ`** [ес-бе-у].

---

**UPDATE** - by [@Sasha](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/4/sasha)

Oleksandr Avramenko (an [associate professor](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docent) at [the Borys Grinchenko Kyiv University](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borys_Grinchenko_Kyiv_University) and a head of the Department of humanities of the Technical lyceum of [the Igor Sikorsky Kyiv Polytechnic Institute](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Sikorsky_Kyiv_Polytechnic_Institute)) in his **[Express lesson about the Ukrainian language #177](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS0jzfuSn8M)** (a part of the "Breakfast with 1+1" TV-show on the "1+1" channel; also [on his site](http://%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80/11/12/374-urok-177-yak-pravilno-vimovliati-zno.html)) claims that `США` ("USA") and `ЗМІ` ("mass media") are to be pronounced as /sʃɑ/ ⟨sshah⟩ and /zmi/ ⟨zmee⟩ — because they are exceptions.

The general rule is the following:

- If there are no adjacent consonants in an abbreviation — then it's read as a usual word: `ЦУМ` — /t͡sum/ ⟨tsum⟩, `ВАТ` — /βat/ ⟨vat⟩, `ЧАЕС` — /t͡ʃɑˈɛs/ ⟨chah-ES⟩.
- If there are adjacent consonants in an abbreviation — then it's spelled by referring every letter with its alphabetic name: `МЗС` — /ɛm zɛ ɛs/ ⟨em zeh es⟩, `СБУ` — /ɛs bɛ u/ ⟨es beh oo⟩.

Answer (score 1):

Взагалi-то треба казати **ЗША**. Так вважає, наприклад, [доктор філологічних наук Олександр Пономарів](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-39076821).

США — це приклад так званого русизму.

Comment: Взагалі-то, за Вашим посиланням Пономарів якраз пише: «Тож її навряд чи треба міняти на ЗША.» Тобто він вважає, що *США* **не треба** міняти на *ЗША*. Але, принаймні, Ваше посилання доводить, що хтось має таку думку («читач Станіслав»).

Comment: Окрім того, навіть якщо писати *ЗША* — Ви не пояснюєте, як це вимовляти ([зеша́] чи [зе́-ше́-а́] чи [зе́-ша́-а́] чи [зиша́] чи [сша́]). Слово *ЗША* вимовити, як є, складно, бо в українській мові дзвінкі перед глухими зазвичай оглушуються (*розшитий* → [росши́тиᵉй]). Тож з вимовою повертаємося до початкового запитання.

Comment: Тож Ваша відповідь, незважаючи на корисну інформацію про інші варіанти абревіатури (хоч їх і не застосовують на офіційному рівні), на жаль, не є відповіддю на запитання.

Comment: Насправді мені теж не зрозуміло, чому *Сполучені* стоїть у назві держави. Адже вся Земля так чи інакше сполучена, якимось рейсами.

Comment: @Sasha Якраз навпаки. В українській мові лише в рідкісних випадках дзвінкі перед глухими оглушуються (а саме в префіксах "роз", "без", "з" і ще декілька винятків: "легко", "вогко", "нігті", "кігті", "дігтяр").  Наприклад, у слові "казка" має вимовлятися саме "з". Навіть більше, глухі перед дзвінкими одзвінчуються: "боротьба" [бород'ба́] є загальновідомим прикладом.
Існує [низка асиміляцій](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Асиміляція_(мовознавство)), через які "розшитий" вимовляється як [рожши́тий] чи [рош:и́тий] (щодо иᵉ - точно поза темою). Вимова [росши́тиᵉй] ненормативна.

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, хм, а я (чи то згадавши [префікси](http://pidruchniki.com/1529052740603/dokumentoznavstvo/vimova_prigolosnih_zvukiv), чи то взагалі згадавши російські фонетичні розбори зі школи) чомусь подумав, що й перед дзвінкими одзвінчується, і перед глухими оглушується. Перепрошую, був не правий. (Ну, в такому разі все одно [жша], а не не [зша], чи не так?)

Comment: @Sasha Гм... Треба виправити вікі :) з+ш на початку слова [ш:] (наприклад, зшити [ш:и́ти]), це всередині слова [жш]. Так написано, наприклад, в "Орфоепічному словнику" Погрібного, сторінка 14, пункт 24.  
Тобто лише [ш:а]

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, взагалі, я зараз зрозумів, що це стосується лише швидкої вимови. При повільній, на мій особистий погляд, можна вимовити і [зша], і [зжша], і що завгодно. «На початку слова» — а з прийменником? «у ЗША» ми хіба вимовимо не [ужша́]? (це сугубо мої екперименти перед дзеркалом, не факти)